# Lightning Web Component Address Input code

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom, screen-flow, address

I would like to know if there is a way to get the full code of the [Basic Input Address Web Lightning Component](https://normad13-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-address/example) (without picklist, I just need to get the style template and use the text input fields with custom property to manipulate some text data).

Best regards,

Leopold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply install the [lightning-base-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components) package, and there you'll find the source for every supported component, including the input address component.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Leo_N1 The components in the npm module run on LWC's LWR (Lightning Web Runtime), which you can read more about on [the main site](https://lwc.dev/). To get them to run in Salesforce, you will have to add a `.js-meta.xml` file for each component and do some additional work, such as fixing any labels. It's not difficult work, but it is going to take some effort.